# powershell how can i find out if user input contains a number that ends with 80

Tags: powershell

I have One Variable contains Number for example

```
$port = 3480
```

how can i use *if else* condition if port number contains `80` in the end

```
if ($port -contains 80)
{
    "true"
}
else
{
    "false"
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `$port % 100 -eq 80`

Comment: `$port -like "*80"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$port = 180

#with like operator
if ($port -like "*80")
{
    Write-Host "true 1"
}

#with regex
if ($port -match "\d{0,}80$")
{
    Write-Host "true 2"
}

#with endwith of string
if ($port.ToString().EndsWith("80"))
{
    Write-Host "true 3"
}

#with modulo math
if (($port - 80) % 100 -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "true 4"
}

#with substring
if ($port.ToString().Length -ge 2 -and $port.ToString().Substring($port.ToString().Length -2) -eq "80")
{
    Write-Host "true 5"
}

# with fool method 1
if (($port -split "")[-2..-3] -join "" -eq "08")
{
    Write-Host "true 6"
}

#with fool method 2
if (($port -split "" | select -Last 3) -join "" -eq "80")
{
    Write-Host "true 7"
}

#imagine your methode... :)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$port = read-host -prompt "Please enter your port number"
If ($port -like "*80") {
    $TRUE
} else {
    $FALSE
}
```

What's happening here:

1. $Port variable receives and stores the answer given to the question asked
2. If $Port is LIKE anything that ends with 80 then it will return $TRUE
3. If $Port doesn't end with 80 then it will equal $FALSE.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (But IMHO, this answer is simple enough that it doesn't need much/any explanation, so it doesn't warrant even a downvote. @Random206, you may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)